# memmove, but with 2 sources

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, memory

I need a function with basically the following signature:

```
void *memmove2 ( void *destination, const void *source1, size_t num1, const void *source2, size_t num2 );
```

It consecutively copies num1 bytes from source1 and num2 bytes from source2 into destination. Any of the arguments can overlap in memory (the destination memory with one of the sources, the sources with each other, or all three). I.e., worst case:

```
char test[10] = "123456789";
memmove2(test, test + 1, 3, test + 2, 4);
```

All copy operations should "see" the memory as it initially was, i.e. this code should result in "234345689". Note that the following doesn't work:

```
char test[10] = "123456789";
memmove(test, test + 1, 3);
memmove(test + 3, test + 2, 4);
```

It would result in "234445689".

The simple solution is to store the result in a temporary memory space and then only copy it back when finished:

```
char test[10] = "123456789";
char temp[7];
memcpy(temp, test + 1, 3);
memcpy(temp + 3, test + 2, 4);
memcpy(test, temp, 7);
```

I wonder if there's a general solution without a buffer that's as large as the number of bytes being copied (no buffer, or a smaller one).

Does this problem have a name I can look up? Does this have a solution with a smaller memory footprint or is there proof that such a solution is impossible?

Comment: I'm wondering where this kind of function would be handy.

Comment: I was solving similar problem but with 2-dimentional images. Came to solution with detecting overlaps. There was two options: save entire overlapping region (fast but more memory), or save a single word of memory which will be copied (in my case it was 32-bit word), but copy from both sources with interleave, word by word (slow but requires fixed small amount of memory).

Comment: @CristiFati I'm writing a C transpiler for an old programming language and I need to support assignment of concatenated strings: (a[0:7] = b[0:3] + c[1:5] in Python). I currently use temporary memory to first assemble the concatenation and then do the assignment but this isn't efficient in the majority of cases where no overlap exists. I'm wondering how to proceed now (keep the old way, find one better solution, or do one of both dynamically based on a static analysis of the code I'm translating).

Comment: This is a problem nobody else is trying to solve.  Looks like you have some code to write.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just copy the strings into the final destination one at a time.

Comment: How do you want to handle overlap if the destination area set from src1 is within the range of src2? (e.g. `memmove2(arr,&arr[5],3,&arr[1],2)`) Left to right? From your last comment _"sources are copied consecutively"_ I'm guessing that the 2nd range _will_ be affected by the 1st range? Maybe you should post your current code. Of course there's a fast way to do it fast with no [or partial] overlap. Rather than a semi-massive `if/else` ladder, I might fill up an array of: `struct segment { void *dst, const void *src, size_t len; }` internally and then just "execute" the moves in the array

Comment: @CraigEstey My current code is basically the last code block in the post.

Comment: I'd be tempted to test if any overlap exists. If there is no overlap, which would be the most common case presumably, then do the simple, efficient moves. If there is an overlap (any overlap) then allocate the temporary buffer. Only those with overlapping moves get penalized, as they should ;-)

Comment: @jarmod how do you test for overlaps? Comparing pointers to different objects is undefined behavior.

Comment: @jarmod I think that's indeed what I'm going to do. I felt like I was missing a simple solution because it seemed like a common problem to have, but based on the comments here, maybe the problem is as difficult as it first looked to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is in the context of building a transpiler. I can just look for overlaps in the original language (which is less complex than C) and avoid the problem entirely. (Of course, that's not an answer to this question, but it is what I'm probably going to do instead of trying to find an answer to this question.)

Comment: @MarkRansom True, but the ranges [`source1`, `source1 + num1`) and [`source2`, `source2 + num2`) shouldn't overlap in case of different objects. Am I right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language?

Comment: @Shawn A dialect of BASIC.

Comment: @Bob__ that's right unless `num1` or `num2` are outside the bounds of the array.  But an optimizing compiler is allowed to assume that they can't overlap by definition, so it won't even emit any code for the test.

Comment: I wonder why just two sources. Doesn't your language support expressions like `a+b+c`?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I do need more than two, I assume an algorithm to do this for two sources will straightforwardly lead to an algorithm for more than two.

Comment: "will straightforwardly lead" That's quite optimistic. I would be very surprised if that was the case.

Answer (score 3):

#### You don't need to store the whole result in a temporary

You only need to store a temporary for one of the spans, not both. Consequently, you only need to store a temporary for the shortest span.

I define a helper structure and a function to help put the shorter span first.

```
typedef struct Span { char *d; const char *p; size_t n; } Span;

void swap ( Span *a, Span *b ) {
    Span tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void arrange ( Span *a, Span *b ) {
    if (a->n > b->n) {
        swap(a, b);
    }
}
```

The move function uses a VLA for the temporary, but you could use or manage allocated memory if you prefer.

```
void *memmove2 ( void *destination,
                 const void *source1, size_t num1,
                 const void *source2, size_t num2 ) {
    Span s1 = { destination, source1, num1 };
    Span s2 = { s1.d + num1, source2, num2 };
    arrange(&s1, &s2);
    /* TODO: The temporary is not always needed. */
    char tmp[s1.n];
    memcpy(tmp, s1.p, s1.n);
    memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
    memcpy(s1.d, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    return destination;
}
```

#### You don't always need a temporary

If the smaller span does not overlap with the result of the movement of the longer span, you don't need to use the temporary.

```
#define PTR_LESS(P,Q) ((uintptr_t)(P) < (uintptr_t)(Q))

void *memmove2 ( void *destination,
                 const void *source1, size_t num1,
                 const void *source2, size_t num2 ) {
    Span s1 = { destination, source1, num1 };
    Span s2 = { s1.d + num1, source2, num2 };
    arrange(&s1, &s2);
    if (PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d)
        ? !PTR_LESS(s2.d, s1.p+s1.n)
        : !PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d+s2.n)) {
        memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
        memmove(s1.d, s1.p, s1.n);
        return destination;
    }
    char tmp[s1.n];
    memcpy(tmp, s1.p, s1.n);
    memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
    memcpy(s1.d, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    return destination;
}
```

#### You can store even less in the temporary

Only the portion of the shorter span that overlaps with the movement result of the larger span needs to be stored.

```
#define PTR_LESS(P,Q) ((uintptr_t)(P) < (uintptr_t)(Q))

void *memmove2 ( void *destination,
                 const void *source1, size_t num1,
                 const void *source2, size_t num2 ) {
    Span s1 = { destination, source1, num1 };
    Span s2 = { s1.d + num1, source2, num2 };
    bool hi;
    arrange(&s1, &s2);
    if ((hi = PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d))
        ? !PTR_LESS(s2.d, s1.p+s1.n)
        : !PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d+s2.n)) {
        memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
        memmove(s1.d, s1.p, s1.n);
        return destination;
    }
    size_t num3 = (hi ? (s1.p+s1.n)-s2.d : (s2.d+s2.n)-s1.p);
    size_t off3 = (hi ? s1.n-num3 : 0);
    size_t off1 = (hi ? 0 : num3);
    Span s3 = { s1.d+off3, s1.p+off3, num3 };
    s1 = (Span){ s1.d+off1, s1.p+off1, s1.n-num3 };
    char tmp[s3.n];
    memcpy(tmp, s3.p, s3.n);
    memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
    memmove(s1.d, s1.p, s1.n);
    memcpy(s3.d, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    return destination;
}
```

#### The logic can be mirrored to store even less

We started the optimization by considering only storing the smaller span in a temporary. Thus, the larger span would be moved first. So we studied whether moving the larger span would cause an overlap with the smaller span.

However, we should follow that by considering whether moving the smaller span would cause an overlap with the larger span, and thus eliminate the need to make a copy. To reduce code repetition, let's define a helper function.

<sub>The `cmov` in the name below is borrowed from the assembly language mnemonic for *conditional move*.</sub>

```
#define PTR_LESS(P,Q) ((uintptr_t)(P) < (uintptr_t)(Q))

bool no_overlap_cmov ( Span s1, Span s2, bool *hi ) {
    if ((*hi = PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d))
         ? !PTR_LESS(s2.d, s1.p+s1.n)
         : !PTR_LESS(s1.p, s2.d+s2.n)) {
        memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
        memmove(s1.d, s1.p, s1.n);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Our code that would call it would look like:

```
    bool hi1, hi2;
    if (no_overlap_cmov(s1, s2, &hi1)) return destination;
    if (no_overlap_cmov(s2, s1, &hi2)) return destination;
```

So now, we should consider which case would cause the minimal amount of overlap. That would be the least amount of memory you would need to allocate for the case that there is one.

With the logic mirrored for both the larger and smaller spans, it is no longer necessary to arrange them in order of span size. Instead, they are arranged in the order that gives the least overlap.

```
void *memmove2 ( void *destination,
                 const void *source1, size_t num1,
                 const void *source2, size_t num2 ) {
    Span s1 = { destination, source1, num1 };
    Span s2 = { s1.d + num1, source2, num2 };
    bool hi1, hi2;
    if (no_overlap_cmov(s1, s2, &hi1)) return destination;
    if (no_overlap_cmov(s2, s1, &hi2)) return destination;
    size_t num3 = (hi1 ? (s1.p+s1.n)-s2.d : (s2.d+s2.n)-s1.p);
    size_t num4 = (hi2 ? (s2.p+s2.n)-s1.d : (s1.d+s1.n)-s2.p);
    if (num4 < num3) {
        num3 = num4;
        hi1 = hi2;
        swap(&s1, &s2);
    }
    size_t off3 = (hi1 ? s1.n-num3 : 0);
    size_t off1 = (hi1 ? 0 : num3);
    Span s3 = { s1.d+off3, s1.p+off3, num3 };
    s1 = (Span){ s1.d+off1, s1.p+off1, s1.n-num3 };
    char tmp[s3.n];
    memcpy(tmp, s3.p, s3.n);
    memmove(s2.d, s2.p, s2.n);
    memmove(s1.d, s1.p, s1.n);
    memcpy(s3.d, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    return destination;
}
```

#### Extending the algorithm from 2 sources to N

For 2 sources, the algorithm is fairly straight forward, and there seems some merit to try to minimize memory copy overhead depending on how the algorithm is used in practice. However, the algorithm amounts to identifying which order of memory movement would result in the least amount of overlapping.

Extending this out to N sources is not really appealing. Iteratively trying each source as the first movement and measuring the amount of overlap caused by doing so, to identify the source with the least overlap would be O(N<sup>2</sup>). Thus the algorithm is O(N<sup>3</sup>) in total, since you will have to re-iterate on the algorithm on the remaining sources, after performing the movement on the one identified.

In comparison, the brute force copy of the entire result into a temporary before copying back would be O(N), at the expense of O(M) cost in memory, where M is the sum of the lengths of the sources. It seems a fair trade for performance and memory, as well as benefiting from being a much easier algorithm to maintain.

Comment: `bool no_overlap` seems like it only tests whether overlap exists; I would rename it to `bool moved_without_overlap`, to make your last version of `memmove2` less confusing to read

Comment: @tucuxi Thanks for the suggestion. I have renamed the function to `no_overlap_cmov`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (bit ugly) solution, that would avoid unnecessary memory operations when no overlaps occur.

*main00.c*:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEST_STR "123456789"


char *tmp = NULL;
size_t tmpLen = 0;


void prepbuf(size_t n)  // Cache temporary and only allocate when required size is greater than existing
{
    if (n == 0) {
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        tmpLen = 0;
    } else if (n > tmpLen) {
        if (tmpLen == 0)
            tmp = malloc(n);
        else
            tmp = realloc(tmp, n);
        tmpLen = n;
    }
}


int disjoint(uintptr_t p0Start, uintptr_t p0End, uintptr_t p1Start, uintptr_t p1End)
{
    return ((p0End <= p1Start) || (p1End <= p0Start));
}


void *memmove2_v1(void *dest, const void *src0, size_t n0, const void *src1, size_t n1)
{
    static int x = 1;
    uintptr_t dStart = (uintptr_t)dest, dEnd = (uintptr_t)dest + n0 + n1,
        s0Start = (uintptr_t)src0, s0End = (uintptr_t)src0 + n0,
        s1Start = (uintptr_t)src1, s1End = (uintptr_t)src1 + n1;
    if (disjoint(dStart, dEnd, s0Start, s0End)
        && disjoint(dStart, dEnd, s1Start, s1End)) {  // No overlaps between any source and destination
        memmove(dest, src0, n0);
        memmove(dest + n0, src1, n1);
    } else if (disjoint(dStart, dEnd, s0Start, s0End)) {  // Overlap between 2nd source and destination (might be affected by the 1st copy)
        prepbuf(n1);
        memcpy(tmp, src1, n1);
        memcpy(dest, src0, n0);
        memcpy(dest + n0, tmp, n1);
    } else {
        prepbuf(n0 + n1);
        memcpy(tmp, src0, n0);
        memcpy(tmp + n0, src1, n1);
        memcpy(dest, tmp, n0 + n1);
    }
    return dest;
}


int main()
{
    char test[10] = TEST_STR;
    printf("Buf: %s\n", test);
    memmove2_v1(test, test + 1, 3, test + 2, 4);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", test);
    strcpy(test, TEST_STR);
    memmove2_v1(test, test + 1, 3, "abcdefgh", 4);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", test);
    strcpy(test, TEST_STR);
    memmove2_v1(test, "ABCDEFGH", 3, test + 2, 4);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", test);
    strcpy(test, TEST_STR);
    memmove2_v1(test, "ABCDEFGH", 3, "abcdefgh", 4);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", test);
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    prepbuf(0);  // @TODO - cfati: deallocate the buffer to avoid memory leaks
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q077888411]> . ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.c
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o out.exe main00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.c  out.exe
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> ./out.exe 
> Buf: 123456789
> Buf: 234345689
> Buf: 234abcd89
> Buf: ABC345689
> Buf: ABCabcd89
>
> Done.
> ```

This is a rudimentary implementation that only differentiates among overlaps between destination and sources (overlaps between sources don't matter, neither doesn't the one between destination and the 1<sup>st</sup> source, as it won't side effect the 2<sup>nd</sup> copy).
A more elaborate one would take into account the number of bytes that actually overlap and only copy around those ones.

Comment: A speedup: Cache the value of `tmp` and don't `free` it. Cache the allocated size as `tlen`. Then, use `realloc` to grow the area if the current `n0 + n1` is greater than `tlen`. _Optional:_ If `tlen` becomes "large", we can trim it with some heuristic if after a large allocation, we see N [much] smaller requests (based on request count or time or both).

Comment: The caching part is easy. It's what we do for growing dynamic array problems here. So, I would do at least that. Leaving a large buffer around isn't to much of a big deal for a runtime on a modern system with lots of memory vs the time spent doing lots of `malloc/free` pairs. IMO ;-)